# Inconsistent honoring of foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

We have the following schema (simplified for readability):

```
CREATE TABLE `group` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `device` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `device_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `group` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Our automated tests create a `device` referencing an existing `group` and then attempt to delete the `group`, which fails due to the default `ON DELETE RESTRICT` clause:

```
Error 1451: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`device`, CONSTRAINT `device_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `group`
(`id`))
```

However, around 25% of the time, the deletion of the `group` succeeds, despite the foreign key constraint. This leads to data inconsistency, where we have a `device` row referencing a `group_id` which does not exist.

- MySQL version is 5.7.10, running the official Docker image
- Tables are InnoDB
- FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS is set to 1

Any ideas why the enforcement of the foreign key constraint could be inconsistent?

Comment: I find it hard to believe this. You have a `not null` foreign key in `device` table. How can it reference a nonexistent record unless someone performed `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0` before deleting? Are you sure you don't have someone in your team who did that?

Comment: We're struggling to understand it as well. The tests are running on my local machine, so there's no possibility of someone else modifying `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`. I would also be very surprised if the Go MySQL driver we're using (`github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`) was doing this behind the scenes.

Comment: If you could enable general logging to get a verbose list of all SQL (including variable setting modifications), that would likely help troubleshoot your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a test fixture library (https://github.com/go-testfixtures/testfixtures) which disabled foreign key checks

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.